# How to cancel the mobile view in the mathstack page

Tags: support, user-interface, mobile-web

I accidentally switch on mobile view on the mathstack page in my laptop (Windows 8)and it is really bad.

How can I return back to normal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the footer to the right it says "full site." Click this and you are back to normal.

Comment: Don't forget to "Disable responsiveness" too to get a real feel of a full design!

Comment: Not sure what you refer to. Could you elaborate.

Comment: @quid  At the very bottom, in the left-most column, you'll see "Disable Responsiveness", and when you click it, to check it out, then you'll see "Enable Responsiveness", so you can "toggle" back and forth (Enable, Disable) to check out any differences.

Comment: @amWhy ah, never noticed that. Thanks. I was looking around in my preferences.